# How many even functions are there from $\{-n, \dots,n \}$ to itself?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $A=\{-n,-n+1, \dots, n-1,n \}$, how many functions $A \to A$ are there,that are even,so they satisfy the condition $f(-x)=f(x), \forall x \in A$?

Is it maybe $(\frac{|A|}{2})^{|A|}$ ?

Comment: Note that $|A|=2n+1$ is odd, so your formula cannot be right (its value is non-integer)

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: What you do is just "count" them.  You look like you are on the right track, by multiplying out all the points that can be "chosen" and excluding the ones that are fixed by symmetry.  Now you just need to notice that all of 0 to n can be chosen, and all of -n to -1 are fixed.  How many is that?  How many different choices are available at each point?

Comment: @evinda: Switch base and exponent, and round the latter up to an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirement of being even means your function is determined by its values on the non-negative integers, and these values can be arbitrary (within the specified range): one can put $f(-i)=f(i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ to complete to an even function. So the answer is the number of maps from the $n+1$ element set $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ to the $2n+1$ element set $A$, which number is $(2n+1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Could you explain me further the sentence: $\text{ So the answer is the number of maps from a } n+1 \text{ element set to a } 2n+1 \text{ element set, which number is } (2n+1)^{n+1}.$

Comment: I've detailed which precise sets are meant. Once a map as indicated in te final sentence is fixed, apply the procedure at the end of my first sentence to construct an even function from $A$ to itself.

Answer (score 2):

The values on negative integers
is determined by the value on the positive integers and nonnegative
integers can be sent to every element of $A$ giving $(2n+1)^{n+1}$ possibilities.

Comment: Edit this to read $(2n+1)^n$ and I'll retract my downvote :)

Comment: It is not necessary that $f(0)=0$. $f(0)=f(-0)$ automatically.

Comment: There are even functions that aren't $0$ at $0$. For example constant functions.

Comment: Thank you. I feel a bit stupid now.

Comment: I haven't understood why it is $(2n+1)^n$. :/ Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @kahen Ah yes, $(2n+1)^n$ counts *odd* functions. We need yet another factor $(2n+1)$ to get the even ones.

Comment: So,what is now the right answer..?I am confused right now.

Comment: @evinda For each $k\in\{0,1,\ldots , n\}$ you have the choice among $2n+1$ values, namely $\{-n,\ldots,n\}$. Thus the count is $\underbrace{(2n+1)\cdots (2n+1)}_{n+1}=(2n+1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: I am confused myself now. I will delete my answer and will (hopefully) come up with a new one.

Comment: @evinda Sorry for my mistake. I hope it is all clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose n=1.Then  A={-1,0,1} are elements of your set A. Now define x goes to x^2n where n€N. That is f from A to A is defined as f(x) = x^2n (x power 2n). Now thing how many even functions are there. There are countably infinite even function.

Comment: The codomain of the function is $A$, not $\mathbb{N}$. There are a finite number of such functions, so there are a finite number of even ones.